# Creating lines of 152 characters and adjusting line endings at ends of words

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, streamreader, peek

I am trying to write a little utility class for myself to do some formatting of text so that each line is as close as possible to 152 characters in length. I have written this code:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Videos\\XSplit\\Luke11\\Luke11fromweb.txt");
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Videos\\XSplit\\Luke11\\Luke11raw.txt");
int count = 152;
char chunk;
do
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        chunk = (char)sr.Read();
        sw.Write(chunk);
    }

    while (Char.IsWhiteSpace((char)sr.Peek()) == false && (char)sr.Peek() > -1)
    {
        chunk = (char)sr.Read();
        sw.Write(chunk);
    }
    sw.WriteLine();
} while (sr.Peek() >= 0);

sr.Close();
sw.Close();
```

The for statement works fine.  It reads and writes 152 characters without flaw. However, there is no guarantee that 152 characters will fall at the end of a word. So I wrote the nested while statement to check if the next character is a space, and if not, to read and write that character. The inner while statement is supposed to stop when it sees that the next character is a space, and then write in the line end statement.

After the reader and writer have gone through the entire document, I close them both and should have a new document where all the lines are approximately 152 characters long and end at the end of a word.

Obviously this isn't working as I anticipated and that is the reason for my question.  Since the for statement works, there is something wrong in my nested while statement (perhaps the condition?) and I am not exiting the program without errors.

Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first line where I instantiate the StreamReader is not showing up in the thread, even though I put three backticks in front of the class name.  The StreamReader is instantiated even though you can't see the first line.

Comment: Clearly edit your question to define "Obviously this isn't working as I anticipated" from your perspective and what is perceived as NOT working

Comment: Does the formatting help reveal that perhaps the conditional check needs to be in the `for` loop? Otherwise it just writes up to 152 characters (end of lines are characters)

Comment: @pm100 yes, late in the day and I typed fast https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim 
FWIW you can use `StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Owner\Videos\XSplit\Luke11\Luke11fromweb.txt"); StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Owner\Videos\XSplit\Luke11\Luke11raw.txt");`

Comment: If I take out the inner while loop the For statement works flawlessly.  The reason for the inner while loop is to advance the reader to the end of the word before writing the line end.  Let's say I've got the word "environment" and the for loop ends at "environ" because that is 152 characters and it puts "ment" on the next line. I want the while loop to write "m", "e", "n", "t", insert the endline, and then go back up to the outer loop.  I think with the inner while loop, I am in an infinite loop and the file doesn't close.

Comment: PLEASE explain what goes wrong. YOu say 'obviously ... ' but at first glance this code looks OK

Comment: @pm100 The inner while loop is behaving like an infinite loop and the file and the program are not closing properly.

Comment: Depending upon where your last "chunk" breaks the end of file your for loop may try to do too much...prob need a EOF check in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your end of file test is incorrect

```
while (Char.IsWhiteSpace((char)sr.Peek()) == false && (char)sr.Peek() > -1)
```

you mean

```
while (Char.IsWhiteSpace((char)sr.Peek()) == false && sr.Peek() > -1)
```

as per docs

> The Peek method returns an integer value in order to determine whether the end of the file, or another error has occurred. This allows a user to first check if the returned value is -1 before casting it to a Char type.

Note *before casting*

Comment: Thank you, I haven't been programming for about 4 years, been doing app support instead.  This exercise is helping me clear the cob webs out of my mind.

Comment: Perhaps put the `sr.Peek() > -1` first on the conditionals to short cycle on that condition

Answer (score -1):

Might I suggest something like the following.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        int maxLength = 152;
        string inputPath = @"c:\Users\Owner\Videos\XSplit\Luke11\Luke11fromweb.txt";
        string outputPath = @"c:\Users\Owner\Videos\XSplit\Luke11\Luke11raw.txt";
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(outputPath))
            {
                File.Delete(outputPath);
            }

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(inputPath))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(outputPath))
                {
                    do
                    {
                        WriteMaxPlus(sr, sw, maxLength);
                    }
                    while (sr.Peek() >= 0);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void WriteMaxPlus(StreamReader sr, StreamWriter sw, int maxLength)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
        {
            if (sr.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                sw.Write((char)sr.Read());
            }
        }

        while (sr.Peek() >= 0 && !Char.IsWhiteSpace((char)sr.Peek()))
        {
            sw.Write((char)sr.Read());
        }

        sw.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: @pm100 Ah, yes; I concentrated on the overall with usings and a private to do a "block"; let me address that in the while loop.